# NoClassDefFoundError when running on Tomcat 7 though Eclipse IDE

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat7

I have two projects in the Eclipse IDE:

1. `MyProject` - Spring MVC project
2. `WebFramework` - a maven project (which is a command layer for MyProject and other projects)

`MyProject` depends on `WebFramework`. The `WebFramework` contains a custom filter that I've wrote: `AddHeadersFilter`.

When trying to run from the IDE on tomcat 7 I've got NoClassDefFoundError for `AddHeadersFilter`. I was able to resolve it by adding the `WebFramework` to the Deployment Assembly settings of the project. Still, now I'm getting:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [com.intel.swiss.framework.webserver.AddHeadersFilter] for bean with name 'addHeadersFilter' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/filter/OncePerRequestFilter
```

Seem like tomcat doesn't find `OncePerRequestFilter` which is located in spring-web. I've validated that the Deployment Assembly settings also contain the Maven Dependencies (even removed and added it again). Also, when right-clicking on the Tomcat server from the Servers view and selecting "Browse Deployment Location..." I can see all the jars inder WEB-INF/lib directory (incl. spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar) but still tomcat complains that the class is not found

When building the WAR outside eclipse (mvn package) this works fine. Any idea what I'm missing here? I need to run this though eclipse in order to be able to debug the code

Comment: Why aren't you simply using maven and the maven eclipse plugin (or the eclipse plugin for maven) to manage your dependencies. That saves you from messing around with class path settings as they should be managed for you.

Comment: I am using maven to manage the dependencies. I have a private Maven repository, both projects are in there and the dependency is managed though maven. The problem is that when Eclipse resolves the dependencies locally, I hit this issue with tomcat